# Driver for hp laserjet p1108 printer

Tags: drivers, 10.04

I have an HP laserjet p1108 printer. Please send me a driver software for the same. I am using Ubuntu 10.04 version.

Answer (score 1):

You need to download the HPLIP package for this (HP Linux Imaging and Printing). This is a proprietary package, and as such is not included in the Ubuntu OS. You can download it [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/hplip/files/hplip/3.15.2/hplip-3.15.2.run/download?use_mirror=switch). It supports thousands of HP printer models, including the p1108. After downloading the file, make it executable (right-click in the File manager) and then run it.